# object attribute is missing after manager.py is restarted when using django redis cache

Tags: django, django-cache

Here is the sample code:

```
class CrossSection(LoggerMixin):
    pass

class CrossSectionFactory(LoggerMixin):
    cross_section_sequence = {}

    def add(self, date):
        cross_section = CrossSection()
        self.cross_section_sequence[date] = cross_section

class Analyzer(LoggerMixin):
    cross_section_factory = None

    def __init__(self, logger=None, **kwargs):
        self.cross_section_factory = CrossSectionFactory(logger=logger, **kwargs)

    def init(self):
        pass

# ----
from django.core.cache import cache

class MyDetail(APIView):
    def post(self, request, analyzer_id, date, format=None):
        analyzer = cache.get("analyzer:1")
        if analyzer is None:
            analyzer = Analyzer(**{})
            analyzer.init()
        cache.set("analyzer:1", analyzer)
```

settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://xxx:xxxxx@xxx.com:6379",
        "TIMEOUT": None,
    }
}
```

If the `manger.py` is not restarted, it can `get` analyzer with all attributes, but if `manger.py` restarts, the other attributes are all good except `analyzer.cross_section_factory.cross_section_sequence`, it become `{}` again.

I tried set/get the `analyzer.cross_section_factory` directly, it seems that works fine.

Do you know why this happens? How do I fix it?

====

Update: I changed the cache key, then I can set/get the `analyzer` now. It seems that the `set` operation didn't work properly, do you know why?